# Why is my adult cat suddenly dragging my kitten around?

Tags: cats, behavior

I recently got a new female kitten and my adult male cat had finally it comfortable with her and was nursing her and keeping beside her.

However recently my kitten got out of the house and was taken in by my neighbours for approximately 10 minutes. Ever since my kitten has been home and has had our scent rubbed back onto her my adult cat has been growling at her and attacking her.Recently he has now been grabbing her by the neck and dragging her towards the hallway to the front door, myself and my husband never let him drag her too far so we are not 100% sure where he is trying to take her.

Please help me as I am unsure whether my kitten is safe to be left alone with the adult cat anymore.

Answer (score 3):

How old is the kitten? Do you have other pets? It would help to know that. You might try giving her a thorough bath with some hypoallergenic baby shampoo. Maybe she picked up a scent that your other cat finds unacceptable. Try that first and then post how it worked. Hopefully, it will get things back on course.
If the kitten is very young and small, you are wise to be concerned. It is not that uncommon for an adult male cat to kill or severely injure a kitten (sorry). That happens for a variety of reasons. If the mother cat is around, a male cat may kill a kitten to reestablish a mating relationship. Since your cat had started to take to the youngster, that’s a good sign. Get her the bath ASAP and keep an eye on them. Try giving your older cat more love and attention-a lot more. He may feel threatened. Always good when introducing a new baby in the house to make sure the older ones gets more attention for the first few weeks. Hope this helps.

Comment: Lovely, I do have other animals but they’re bunnies and the cats don’t seem that bothered by them. I ended up giving the kitten a bath and then hugging her so she smelt like myself and my husband again. The adult male cat has been receiving more attention and he seems to be more accepting of her. My husband gives the older male cat more attention whereas I give the kitten more attention. However my male cat doesn’t seem too keen on cuddles with me as much as he is with my partner. But my male cat has been more accepting since the bath and cuddles so fingers crossed it’s all good from now on :)